# How does this odd BigQuery SQL syntax work?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm relatively new to BigQuery but I've been writing SQL for years; so you can imagine my surprise when I found a query written by a colleague like this: (simplified)

```
SELECT
    t1.user_id,
    t2.value,
    MAX(t1.order_id) 
FROM orders t1, 
    (SELECT 
         value
     FROM products) t2
WHERE t1.order_id > t2.value
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

He is selecting from two tables but without joining them - each table is just separated by a comma! Is this something normal in SQL or a join shorthand unique to BigQuery? How does it work?

Comment: That's the original way to join. But the explicit JOIN from 1992 is preferred. Just a few years I learned a 60+ year old coworker to use the explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's standard SQL, works everywhere (at least the table list part. `GROUP BY 1, 2` doesn't work everywhere), and is the same as this:

```sql
SELECT
    t1.user_id,
    t2.value,
    MAX(t1.order_id) 
FROM orders t1
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT value
  FROM products
) t2
WHERE t1.order_id > t2.value
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

If you list more than one table in the `FROM` clause, you're just going to get a cross product between all the listed tables.

Comment: I'd rather do it as `INNER JOIN (SELECT value FROM products) t2
ON t1.order_id > t2.value`.

Comment: @jarlh: Yes, but that's another refactoring step, which I thought wouldn't help explain what table lists do.

Comment: And no derived table at all would be the next step!

Comment: @jarlh: Feel free to offer a 7-step-refactoring answer! :)